# Only 3 fonts listing under Word 2010 and Publisher 2010 running under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-office-2010

I am running Windows 7 (brand new computer from Dell with Win 7 factory installed) but when I installed Word 2010 and Microsoft Publisher 2010 and go into either of those programs and try to pick a font, there are only 3 system fonts listed.

If I go into my Fonts directory I can see all of my system fonts (dozens of them).  But under Word 2010 and Publisher 2010, I only see three fonts listed.

I am using my admin account under Windows 7 so permissions is not a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuild the Font Cache.

> The Windows operating system has a
>   font cache file that is located here:
>   C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT
>
> Delete this file, and restart your
>   system.

Source: http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/49179-windows-7-64-bit-fonts-not-shown-4.html